# How to use $scope.watch for a scope inside a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to watch the model `search.value` **inside** my custom directive.

How do to this ?

**HTML :**

```
<div search></div>
```

**DIRECTIVE :**

```
app.directive('search', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: 'template/app/inputSearch.html',
    replace: true,
    controller: function() {

    },
    link: function (scope, element) {

        /* ... */
        scope.$watch(......., function(value) {

        });

    }
  };
});
```

**TEMPLATE :**

```
<div class="search-parent">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.value" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
controller: function($scope) { 
    $scope.$watch('search.value', function(newVal, oldVal) {

    });
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try it. But why do you put it in the controller function ?

Comment: Either way should work. It just depends on how you want to organize your code within `link` and `controller` functions. I like this approach because I can test my code with controller outside directive first, then if it works, the code can be cut-n-paste right into directive's controller. With `link`, you have to rename `$scope` to `scope`.